# Printing unique node elements from an unsorted linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I wasn't sure exactly how to word this so bear with me and let me know if I can clarify anything.
I have a linked list of nodes represented as structures where each node has the following contents:
Type, Description, Quantity

I need to print out all of the unique "types". If multiple nodes share a type, I only print that type once.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing a set. Then iterate the list, adding *types* to this set.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a homework, but the slower algorithm should be something like this

```
make an array to hold types

loop though all the elements

search the element in the collection
if only found one print the I-th element
if more than one, compare the index, only print if the first found index is equal to the current I, otherwise skip

search the type array for type, if none found
put type in the array made in the first line
and print
otherwise skip
```